# How can I get the user id from the deauthorize callback? (sdk v6)

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I know that using FacebookSignedRequest.Parse is no longer possible in the sdk v6.
That is why I want to know how can I retreive the user id when my callback URL is called.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FacebookSignedRequest.Parse has been moved to FacebookClient in v6.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient { AppId = "app_id", AppSecret = "app_secret" };
dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest(Request.Params["signed_request"]);
```

or

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
dynamic signedRequest = fb.ParseSignedRequest("app_secret", Request.Params["signed_request"]);
```

Comment: Sorry I missed it :), Thank you!